# How far do taxis from Incheon Airport go?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, south-korea, seoul

I have an event in Yeoncheon, South Korea (near the North / South border). My flight takes me to Incheon Airport, then I need to *somehow* get from there to Yeoncheon. I've researched and there doesn't seem like a lot of options; either train or bus is going to take multiple transits and probably at least 4 hours to get there.

1. Can I take a taxi at Incheon Airport and ask the driver to take me
   there? Will the driver be willing me to go to a destination that's so far
   away?
2. Considering it's around 2~3 hours drive, how much will it
   cost?
3. If a direct taxi ride is impossible, which "taxi hubs" should I go to get there with multiple taxi rides?

Comment: You don't want to rent a car? Check Rome2rio for options.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany no, since I will be staying at the same place in Yeoncheon for over a week. I won't drive around. I just want to get there.

Comment: Note that the [DMZ-Train](http://www.letskorail.com/ebizbf/EbizBfAboutDmzTrain.do) (charming name) runs every day except Tuesday from Seoul Station to Yeoncheon, taking about two hours.  But there's only one train a day, leaving at about 9:30 AM, so that may not work well with your flight.

Comment: If a driver declines to ride you on so far away, how about taking multiple taxis?

Comment: Long-distance taxis are usually _hugely_ expensive. If the drive is already two-to-three hours and the train is at most four, taking the train seems like a no-brainer.

Comment: Taxi is more than time. It's the comfort of riding in a car, and the comfort of arriving right at the door step. I'd avoid taking a train hauling my briefcase in unfamiliar territory after a long and tired flight by all means possible.

Comment: While taking a taxi the whole way is a reasonable choice in perplexed by the suggestion that it is now comfortable than the train.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to ride the Airport bus from the ICN to Dongducheon (#7001)- the closest town to Yeoncheon, and take a taxi from there. It will save you time, money, and headaches.

::EDIT::

I am sorry that I did not carefully read your question.
There is a way to get there. You can use what is referred to as "콜택시" and reserve a ride with a fixed price. Only operates in Korean, so ask a friend to arrange it if you can't yourself.
[image]

Comment: I wonder how much it takes to ride it on...

Comment: Call them and find out

Answer (score 1):

You can get to Seoul by any taxi and then get International Taxi from there: https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Seoul/Yeoncheon-gun-Gyeonggi-do-South-Korea

But have your addresses writen in Korean on a piece of paper or in a mobile phone because almost no taxi driver in Korea speaks english.

Comment: This does not answer the question of whether a taxi driver might actually be willing to drive that far. It just says that yes it can in theory be done by taxi.

Comment: It answers all 3 points asked in the question.

Comment: It doesn't answer `Will the driver be willing me to go to a destination that's so far away?`. The OP is concerned about the length of the taxi ride. It is not uncommon for taxi drivers to refuse to drive very far from their hub since that will most probably mean driving back without passengers thus wasting time petrol and money.

Comment: In the linked site it says the International Taxi will get him there for 60€ - 75€. It is even possible to reserve the taxi before. What more is required here to answer `Yes, that will get you there`?

Comment: @cdm So Rome2Rio links to the provider, intltaxi.co.kr, but that site is *not* clear about how far out of Seoul they'll go.